# Making scientific notation the default for tick labels with large numbers

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

How do I set parameters of matplotlib so that all plots in a notebook (whether produced by matplotlib, seaborn or pandas) use scientific notation on axis ticks for large numbers above a certain threshold by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the rcParam `axes.formatter.limits`:

> ```
> axes.formatter.limits : -7, 7 # use scientific notation if log10
>                               # of the axis range is smaller than the
>                               # first or larger than the second
> ```

This can be done with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-7, 7)
```

This should work for any plot that uses a `ScalarFormatter`.

If plots created via seaborn or pandas do not use a `ScalarFormatter`, you have no knob to turn for automatically setting those parameters and would need to do it manually, depending on the plot in use.

Comment: Indeed, this does not affect the plots generated with pandas.DataFrame.plot, unfortunately.